# Google Cloud run / Trobleshooting pubsub 403

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam, google-cloud-run

Just followed [the tutorial available here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub), everything's clear; apparently nothing blocks

The configured run service iam :

`gcloud beta run services get-iam-policy $CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE_NAME`

returns

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@$PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/run.invoker
etag: BwWRVC2n5Ek=
version: 1
```

The subcribtion :

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe $app_subscription`

returns

```
ackDeadlineSeconds: 10
expirationPolicy:
  ttl: 2678400s
messageRetentionDuration: 604800s
name: projects/$PROJECT_NAME/subscriptions/$app_subscription
pushConfig:
  oidcToken:
    serviceAccountEmail: cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@$PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  pushEndpoint: https://$CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE_NAME-he6agqsita-ew.a.run.app/
```

However, The service don't accept anything from the pubsub trigger (keeps returning 403).

The tutorial does not explicitely tell one to add this role to a service accounts. But as experienced, the `add-iam-binding` command on the run instance does not seem to be the correct step to take

[image]

the Service account token creator is also correctly set on the pusub service account

This happens in a managed context, not gke. The run service is in europe

Is it missing on the tutorial ? Is that expected or am I missing something somewhere ?

Comment: You have added `cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@$PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to Cloud Run but Pub/Sub is using `PROJECT_NAME@$PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. Different service accounts.

Comment: @JohnHanley sorry no it is a typo rewriting/hiding names; the service accounts match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grand the TokenCreate role to the pubsub service-agent service account

Here the command line that I use

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <ProjectId> \
    --role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator \
    --member=serviceAccount:service-<ProjectNumber>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

[Copy paste of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#integrating-pubsub) in fact

Comment: edited my question everything's set correctly as described in the tutorial, which is quite well done and clear. so frustrated not to have it working as advertised :s.. the things should work

Comment: the service is in europe-west1 region, could it matter here ?

Comment: Pubsub and cloud run are in the same project?

Comment: yup they do. Just got back at it, looks like the 403 disapeared. maybe due to the beta state of cloud run, idk. a bit weird but looks like it works perfectly now

Comment: Yes, maybe beta issue. Or IAM latency. Maybe you have to wait 2 or 3 minutes for new roles propagation. But I think that your tests took more than 5 minutes before writing here. Strange in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In the section titled [Integrating with Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#integrating-pubsub), there's a tab widget that asked you to select Cloud Run or Cloud Run on GKE.

For Cloud Run, step (a) is to use a command which associates the service account to the `roles/run.invoker` role in the context of a specific service.

```
gcloud beta run services add-iam-policy-binding pubsub-tutorial \
   --member=serviceAccount:cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --role=roles/run.invoker
```

This associates the invoker role with the service account, but only for the specified Cloud Run service. If you add this role to the service account generally it will be able to invoke any Cloud Run service. The tutorial takes the least privilege approach.

For Cloud Run on GKE, the **invoker role is not supported**, and the instructions in (d) ask that you add custom code to validate the ID Token sent as part of the Pub/Sub push request.

Comment: I should have had specified it; i'm on a managed context. associating the service account to the service does not allow the described use (am getting 403)

Comment: I've added the commands used to check; Are those outputs corrects ? Things should work

Comment: From your question, the service account in the IAM binding is not the same as the service account in the Pub/Sub subscription. Could you double check that the same service account is used for both?

Comment: sorry yes that was a typo rewriting, things match